# Regex to require both [^/] and another user-defined regex

Tags: regex, go

Suppose a user gave `str = "[a-z]"`. How can I match `[^/]` *and* `[a-z]`?

I want some thing like `"/[^/]&" + str + "/"`. It should match `asdf` but not `a/sdf`.

Comment: is `str` always a character class or is it potentially more broad?

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: The user can give anything.

Comment: Writing in Golang

Comment: So why not run the expression against two separate regexes? Why does it have to be combined?  If this is for validation, you can just run it twice against user input first and then against the slash for the second pass.

Comment: Just note that `[^/]` will also match `[a-z]`.

Comment: and you may use `(?:[^/]|[a-z])`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, 1) The `[a-z]` is user-supplied and will vary (otherwise one could simply use `[a-z]`). 2) `(?:[^/]|[a-z])` matches `!`, so that's not right.

Comment: @Travis Use `\`^(?:[^/]|[a-z])+$\``

Answer (score 0):

Best to do the checks separately.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    str := "test"
    user_provided_pattern := "^[a-z]+\\z"

    matched := false
    matched_slash, _ := regexp.MatchString("/", str)
    if !matched_slash {
       matched_user, err := regexp.MatchString(user_provided_pattern, str)
       if err != nil {
          panic(err)
       }

       if matched_user {
          matched = true
       }
    }

    fmt.Println(matched)
}
```

*This is my first go program —I've never even seen a go program before— so please excuse any oddities.*